# Blue light on NodeMCU Esp8266 doesn't blink

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

The blue light on this Esp8266 used to flash blue when plugged in. Now it flashes once when plugged in then not at all. After running the flasher https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-flasher to try to wipe the memory (thats what that does right?) and the light flashed while the flasher worked in the background then stopped once again completely. (I know i'm using the word flash alot).

I'd just like to make sure the data is wiped clean from my NodeMCU Esp8266 so that I can upload new programs to it. Currently thinking it may have been since the blue light stopped flashing and all other functionality seems bleak. Does any one have any idea wha this means?

***Update*** I admittedly tried uploading several projects onto it without making sure everything was still good to go.

Comment: you might have had some demo firmware on there; it should not blink under any standard firmware

Answer (score 1):

The NodeMCU has an LED but its only used to signal if you upload a script or restart the board. You can't use it as an LED for your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no error messages when compiling and uploading, your nodemcu/esp8266 should be fine. I assume that it came with a "blink" sketch uploaded, so when you plugged it in, the builtin led started to blink. Then you uploaded other code so now it only blinks when plugged in, resetted or when the firmware tells it to again.

I already fried two nodemcu's and one wemos d1 mini so that's another option too I guess. :) But you could tell, because you'd get error messages when uploading.